# Why does Word think there's Italian in a document that shouldn't contain any?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

When some documents are opened in word there is the warning

> MISSING PROOFING TOOLS  this document contains text in Italian (Italy)
>   which isn't being proofed.

The only option is "never show again".

1. There shouldn't be any Italian text in the document. How can I find out where Word thinks the Italian text is?
2. How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some text in the document was marked as Italian, perhaps while pasting text from the Web.

Do not choose the "Never show again" option.
To undo :

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire document
2. Click on the Language panel at the bottom-left border
   [image]
   Or alternatively, in the Review tab, Language group, click Language, and then click Set Proofing Language.
3. In the Language dialog that opens choose your language
4. Click OK and the document should now be entirely of that language

If the problem still exists, in the Review tab, Changes group,
choose Accept -> Accept All Changes and Stop Tracking, then repeat the above.

Comment: This does resolve the issue, but out of curiosity, is there a way to find out which text Word actually thought was the other language?

Answer (score 1):

The way I was able to remove Dutch (Netherlands) text in my document, was to do a find/replace.  I had to click in the find box, and select the Format, Language Dutch (Netherlands), and then click into the replace box, and again select the Format, Language English (United States).  Then I had to do a few search and replace alls to remove all of the dutch language.  Thanks to the Adrian and Reddy who helped me see the answer.  The key is to not have any text in the find and replace boxes - but you have to click into them before changing the language you are searching for and the language you are wanting to replace the searched language for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Office Proofing Tools for your language.

For **home users** check [Language Accessory Pack for Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f#ID0EAADAAA=Newer_versions).

For **enterprise users** with volume licensing: [Customize language setup and settings for Office 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/DeployOffice/office2016/customize-language-setup-and-settings-for-office-2016#DownloadLIPandProofTools).

> After you install the language accessory pack, you must configure
>   Office for your new language preferences. Open any Office program and
>   then click **File > Options > Language**.

See Step 2 at [Language Accessory Pack for Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f#ID0EAADAAA=Newer_versions) page.

Nice article about types of Office language packs: [Download Free Office 2016 Language Packs (All Languages)](https://www.itechtics.com/download-free-office-2016-language-packs-languages/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I ended up adding Italian(Italy) to the languages for proofing, and the error went away.

I however was also curious to what words in my document were "Italian" since none should be, so I had a little play around. I found that I was able to find them using the advanced search.  (Note: I am running Office 2016)

In the advanced search:

1. Click "More" if you haven't already.
2. Under "Format" select "Language".

[image]

3. Select your  language.

[image]

Word then changes the "Format" to be your language (in my case Italian). With nothing in the "Find what", hits all the Italian words.

[image]

Sorry for the links to the images, I can't post images yet.